# Website button on application?

Tags: desktop-application

Is it bad to keep a button that links to your website on your application? Do most people who use it see this as annoying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't mind a link to the web site on a menu, for example under the Help menu. (eg. Help -> Website)

There are times when you want to:

- Look up documentation
- Check for an upgrade
- Get help
- Check system requirements
- View tutorials
- Refer the app to a friend

... and can't remember exactly what site the app came from, so some sort of link back to the site is nice.

You could put it as a button or link on the Help -> About dialog.